# How to get not editted object from form with spring

Tags: html, spring, model, controller, thymeleaf

I have a simple controller for checkout in my application
At the beginning, we transfer to the form just the object of our order:

```
@GetMapping
    public String getOrderForm(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("orderForm", new OrderDto());
        model.addAttribute("deliveryType", orderService.getDeliveryTypeList());
        model.addAttribute("paymentType", orderService.getPaymentTypeList());
        return "create-order";
    }
```

After that, the user fills in 2 fields in this object and it all comes in the following method:

```
    @PostMapping
    public String addNewOrder(@ModelAttribute("orderForm") @Valid OrderDto orderDto,
                              @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails currentUser,
                              BindingResult bindingResult,
                              Model model,
                              RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
        User userFromBd = userRepository.findByEmail(currentUser.getUsername());
        orderDto.setUser_id(userFromBd.getId());
        List<AddressDto> savedAddress = addressService.getAllSaved(orderDto.getUser_id());
        model.addAttribute("savedAddress", savedAddress);
        model.addAttribute("addressForm", new AddressAdditionDto());
        return "order-address";
    }
```

Here we pass other objects into the form and let the user fill them in. This is what the form looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add new order</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div th:each="address : ${savedAddress}">
        <p>
            <span th:text="*{address.country}"></span>
        </p>
        <p>
            <span th:text="*{address.city}"></span>
        </p>
    </div>

    <form th:method="POST" th:action="@{/order/savedaddress}">
        <td>Choose adress:</td>
        <select name="addressId">
            <span th:each="address : ${savedAddress}">
                   <option th:value="${address.id}"
                           th:text="${address.id}"></option>
            </span>
        </select>
        <br>
        <label>
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Select"/>
        </label>
    </form>
<p><a href="/">Home</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

In this form, there is no interaction with our original OrderDTO object. All data from this form comes in the following method:

```
    @PostMapping("/savedaddress")
    public String addAddress(@ModelAttribute("orderForm") @Valid OrderDto orderDto,
                             @RequestParam(value = "addressId", required = false) Long addressId,
                             BindingResult bindingResult,
                             Model model){
        model.addAttribute("orderForm", orderDto);
        if(orderDto.getPaymentType().equals("CARD")) {
            model.addAttribute("savedCard", cardService.getAllByUserId(orderDto.getUser_id()));
            model.addAttribute("cardForm", new CardRegisterDto());
            return "order-card";
        }
        return "order-finish";
    }
```

But the problem is that my OrderDTO object already comes to this method completely empty. That is, the fields that have already been filled in in the previous forms are empty. With what it can be connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add annotation @SessionAttributes (types = {OrderDto.class})
above the class

Answer (score 2):

I think you have not used the OrderDto object in your HTML file that may be the reason to get an empty object as a ModelAttribute. You can use th:object in your form
like:

```
 <form th:method="POST" th:action="@{/order/savedaddress}" th:object="${orderForm}">
  <input type="hidden" th:field="*{user_id}">
   '''
    other code
   ''' 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:

```
<form th:method="POST" th:action="@{/order/savedaddress} th:object={orderForm}">
    <input type="hidden" th:value="${orderForm.user_id} name=userId">
    <td>Choose adress:</td>
    <select name="addressId">
        <span th:each="address : ${savedAddress}">
               <option th:value="${address.id}"
                       th:text="${address.id}"></option>
        </span>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label>
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Select"/>
    </label>
</form>
```